# Python Dask dataframe fail to sort_values by a column of constant value

Tags: python, dask

The below dask dataframe fail to sort by constant value column rand3, with the below error, but can sort by random value column rand1.  Anyone know why and any way to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
import dask.bag as db

NumberOfSample = 50
NumberOfPartition = 2
SortByColumn = ['rand3', 'rand1', 'rand2']

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame("Happy", index=list(range(0,NumberOfSample)), columns=['x', 'y']) 
pandas_df['rand1'] = np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=NumberOfSample) / 10
pandas_df['rand2'] = np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=NumberOfSample) / 10
pandas_df['rand3'] = 1

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=NumberOfPartition)

print('ddf before sorting is with len ' + str(len(ddf)))
print(ddf.head(NumberOfSample, NumberOfPartition))

ddf_sorted2 = ddf.sort_values(by=['rand3'], ascending=True, inplace=False)
# ddf_sorted2 = ddf.sort_values(by=['rand1'], ascending=True, inplace=False)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\PythonProjects\TradeAnalysis\Test\untitled0.py:29 in <module>
    ddf_sorted2 = ddf.sort_values(by=['rand3'], ascending=True, inplace=False)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py:4470 in sort_values
    return sort_values(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\shuffle.py:159 in sort_values
    df = rearrange_by_divisions(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\shuffle.py:459 in rearrange_by_divisions
    df3 = rearrange_by_column(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\shuffle.py:486 in rearrange_by_column
    df = df.repartition(npartitions=npartitions)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py:1319 in repartition
    return repartition_npartitions(self, npartitions)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py:6970 in repartition_npartitions
    npartitions_ratio = df.npartitions / npartitions

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

........................................................
........................................................
........................................................

Comment: What is the expected outcome when sorting on a constant? Are you trying to prevent an edge case?

Comment: kind of to prevent an edge case, but ultimately I am trying an approach of sorting a dask dataframe with multiple key columns, and just in case any one of those column is constant value, it will still work.  I can post my full sample code of sort_values() by multi columns here as well if you wish.

Comment: yeah this definitely should work so if this is a real reproducible behavior it would be good to get to the bottom of what's going wrong. can you update your question to post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback), all the way from `"Traceback (most recent call last)"` to `"SomeTypeOfError: Error Message"`, and include the traceback in a [code block](/help/formatting) (e.g. by enclosing it with triple backticks at the start and end?

Comment: hmmm - I can run your example straight through with dask version `2022.04.0`. what version are you using? you can print out the version with `import dask; print(dask.__version__)`

Comment: Mine is 2022.02.1.  So I just need to pip install dask again and it will be the latest version?